# Grey Clone-Brand Brick With a Single Short Tube on the Bottom?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I've had this brick for a while, and I've long wondered what it is.

It's a LEGO-compatible 2x4 brick, colored almost exactly the same as the old medium grey. There are no identifying marking, and the only marking of any kind is a single line on the bottom, which I assume is a `1`.

The most distinguishing feature is that it has only 1 tube on the bottom, and it doesn't reach all the way down.

I originally found it in a bucket of otherwise genuine LEGO pieces years back, so no clues there.

[image: top]

[image: bottom]

I'm quite certain it's not a genuine LEGO piece, but it is an odd piece and I've long wondered what it's from?

Comment: I don't know about this clone piece, but on original pieces the tubes at the bottom are not conical (and from the picture it doesn't look like that here either), so please don't call them cones. When I saw the topic I struggled a lot to imagine what you might mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As luck would have it I stumbled upon your answer today sorting through my own mess[image]. It's a Tyco brick. Although the picture doesn't show it, the one I have has a white sticker with the word "DANGER" in red on one side. Hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is indeed a "Tyco" brick. Probably from the mid 80's. I use to have a few of them. I think the great bricks like that were adapter bricks for Tyco's version of Duplo.